# Regex match HTML tag and attributes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match html tag name along with it's attributes. In the example below, I am trying to match `div`, `class`, `style` and `id`.

```
$html='<div class="nav" style="float:left;" id="navigation">';
preg_match_all("/(([^<]\w+\s)|(\S+)=)/", $html, $match);
```

This returns the array like below.

As you can see, the correct results are kept in Array[2] and Array [3]. I was wondering if it is possible to put the results in a single array, perhaps in Array[1]? Not sure how to do this.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => div 
        [1] => class=
        [2] => style=
        [3] => id=
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => div 
        [1] => class=
        [2] => style=
        [3] => id=
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => div 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => class
        [2] => style
        [3] => id
    )

)
```

Comment: Don't use regexes for HTML parsing. Use a special parser instead.

Comment: I'm just experimenting with regex. In real projects I may use a parser but I'd like to know how this can be done with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple regex :

```
(?<=<)\w++|\b\w++(?==)
```

where `(?<=...)` is a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and `(?=...)` a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

example:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=<)\w++|\b\w++(?==)~', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But if you use several capturing parenthesis and you want the result in an unique array, you can use the [branch reset](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) feature. Example (without lookarounds):

```
preg_match_all('~(?|<(\w++)|\b(\w++)=)~', $html, $matches);
```

(about the `++`, it is a possessive quantifier that informs the regex engine that it doesn't need to backtrack *(among other things, backtrack positions are not recorded)*, this increase performances of the pattern but this is not essential *(in particular for small strings)*. You can have more information about this feature [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html))

Comment: Great. That seems to give a result that I am after. I'm not sure why you've used double `+` as in `\w++`. I tried `(?<=<)\w+|\w+(?==)` and it seems to give the same result. Maybe there is something I am not understanding.

Comment: @user1448031: I have added some reference about this strange thing.